# The calculation of small-worldness via the Brain Connectivity Toolbox

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

I’d like to calculate the global clustering coefficient (CC), characteristic path length (Lp), global efficiency (Eglob), and small-worldness (SW) with the Brain Connectivity Toolbox (BCT, https://sites.google.com/site/bctnet/).
I have 2 groups, healthy controls and patients. The patient group exhibited lower CC and longer Lp than healthy controls.

According to my knowledge, it’s more possible to find that the patient group has a lower SW in this case. However, my script calculates higher SW (100 random networks were generated via null_model_und_sign.m) in the patient group (not significant, but the mean values are slightly higher than healthy controls across 3 sparsity levels).

My script calculates the same values for CC and Eloc as the GraphVar toolbox (https://www.nitrc.org/projects/graphvar/) but provides similar but different values of Lp and SW since it uses an old version of charpath.m function for Lp and the random networks generated during the calculation of SW.

I'd like to know if I wrote the script correctly.

In the beginning, I generated random networks based on the original network and get almost double SW values, compared with GraphVar toolbox. Then, I noticed that the random networks should be generated with the same setting as the networks (i.e. threshold range, number of nodes), thus, I use

```
W0_thr = null_model_und_sign(W_thr);
```

instead of

```
W0 = null_model_und_sign(W_nrm);
W0_thr = threshold_proportional(W0,spa);
```

The current version provides similar SW values to GraphVar toolbox, but patient group still has slight higher SW values than healthy controls.
The following is my current script:

```
% load the weighted and undirected networks (a Pearson correlation matrix)
W = CorrMatrix;
% Normalize the matrix
W_nrm = weight_conversion(W, ‘normalize’);
% Apply the sparsity/threhold (0.2) to filtering out weak connections
W_thr = threshold_proportional(W_nrm,0.2);

% Calculate global CC (Mean_C)
C = clustering_coef_wu(W_thr);
Mean_C = mean(C);

% Calculate global Lp (lambda)
L = weight_conversion(W_thr, ‘lengths’);
[D, B] = distance_wei(L);
lambda = charpath(D,0,0);

% Calculate SW
% Generate 100 random networks
Crand = ;
Lrand = ;
for j = 1:100
W0_thr = null_model_und_sign(W_thr);
% Cluster Coefficient (WU)
C = clustering_coef_wu(W0_thr);
% the average cluster coefficient in the specific sparsity.
Crand(j) = mean(C);
% Chracteristic Path Length
L = weight_conversion(W0_thr, ‘lengths’);
[D, B] = distance_wei(L);
lambda_2 = charpath(D,0,0);
Lrand(j) = lambda_2;
end
% average values to get random CC and random Lp
rCC = mean(Crand);
rLp = mean(Lrand);
% Calculate normalized CC and normalized Lp
nCC = Mean_C/rCC;
nLp = lambda/rLp;
% Small-Worldness
SW = nCC/nLp;
```